# Convert array values to a comma-delimited string, with numbers replaced by '?'

Tags: php, string

My array:

```
$numbers = array(1, 3, 5);
```

Simply, I need to change numbers with `?` question mark and **separated** with `,` comma.

```
// Output (array has 3 items): 
$string = '?, ?, ?';
```

Comment: confused, but i think you may want implode()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of [str_repeat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) and [count](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php). Then use [rtrim](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) to clean up the trailing comma:

```
$numbers = array(1, 3, 5);
$str = str_repeat('?, ', count($numbers));
$str = rtrim($str, ', ');
echo $str;

// output: ?, ?, ?
```

Answer (score 4):

One-liner for fun:

```
echo implode(", ", array_map(function($v){ return "?"; }, $numbers));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$numbers = array(1,2,3);
$questions = array();
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($numbers);$i++)
    $questions[] = '?';
$string = implode(', ',$questions);
```

EDIT: improved by using array_fill

```
$numbers = array(1,3,5);
$string = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($numbers), '?'));
echo $string;
```

Comment: it's also good one, but webbiedave's answer is better i think because of combination of str_repeat and count..

Comment: This is a good answer too but as the array gets larger it will be much slower than using simple string creation (str_repeat) because it has to create a whole new array.

Answer (score 1):

Could be?

```
$arr= array(1,2,3);
echo wordwrap(sprintf("%'?".count($arr)."s",'' ), 1, ", ", true);
```

Edit for:

```
$arr= array(1,2,3);
$max = count($arr);
for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
   echo '?',(($i==($max-1))?'':', ');
}
```

Comment: it works as well, but you use sprintf(). i think not better than count and str_repeat.. thanks thought!

Answer (score 0):

use function implode.

```
$numbers = array(1, 3, 5);
$string = implode(", ", $numbers);
echo $string;
```

Comment: Your output: `1, 3, 5`. But i need to change numbers with question mark like this: `?, ?, ?`